# How to set Tint in NavigationView to some icons

Tags: android, navigationview

I want to keep some icons not tinted, and some tinted.
Now I have:

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/menu_icons_selector"
```

It tints all icons.

I'm trying to make all icons not tinted

```
mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

and then

```
mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(4).getIcon().setColorFilter(redColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

to set tint only to 4th item, but this not working - all icons are now not tinted, and 4th also not tinted.

Comment: I just see you already use `setColorFilter` . In that case my answer probably won't help you much if it doesn't work (but you can leave it for future reference). Try removing the `app:itemIconTint` and `setItemIconTintList`. That should work I believe. Also make sure it is actually called. Mine runs in onPostCreate().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is working for me....
In this way you can tint individual Navigation `MenuItem` Icon Color Programmatically

```
navigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navItem1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.RED,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can "wrap" the icon as a drawable (res/drawable) and apply the applicable tint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_icon"
    android:tint="@color/pink"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your icons are in an `ImageView` you can use `setColorFilter`.

Like in this example from the app I am working on, where the icon is tinted when it is selected in the navigationDrawer.

```
 ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

 iconView.setColorFilter(selected ?
     getResources().getColor(R.color.navdrawer_icon_selected_tint) :
     getResources().getColor(R.color.navdrawer_icon_tint));
```

You can apply `setColorFilter` also directly to the `Drawable`.

Comment: Is it possible to get ImageViews of icons from NavigationView?

Comment: I don't think there is an `ImageView` inside NavigationView. You apply `setColorFilter` directly on the `Drawable` which you get from `getIcon()`. There is no need to get an `ImageView` since `ImageView` also applies it to the `Drawable`.

Comment: As I said, I already setting ColorFilter to item, but it isn't working

Comment: I would try removing your first 2 lines. `app:itemIconTint` and `setItemIconTintList(null)` and only keep the third line you posted. If that doesn't work, I don't know :(